# How to query with $in with multiple arrays

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, nosql

I´m developing a filter system that you can filter a set of tv´s by price, brand and screen size. Now, I´m able to filter the tv´s by brand like follows:

```
db.tvs.find({brand: {$in: ['LG', 'Samsung']}})
```

And it works.

But right now, I´d like to do the same but with multiple filters (price and screensize), something like this:

```
db.tvs.find({brand: {$in: ['LG', 'Samsung']}}, {screensize: {$in: ['37', '42']}})
```

It is possible?

Answer (score 3):

You didn't have to use $and... You could do it like this:

```
db.tvs.find({brand: {$in: ['LG', 'Samsung']}, screensize: {$in: ['37', '42']}})
```

The only difference with

with your version

```
db.tvs.find({brand: {$in: ['LG', 'Samsung']}}, {screensize: {$in: ['37', '42']}})
```

is that i did not close the first brackets {} after the brand and didn't open a new one before screensize. You need to have them all in the same bson object

A more simple case to understand is this:

```
db.tvs.find( {brand : "LG" , screensize : '37'})
```

Answer (score 0):

I did it.

With the $and operator.

```
db.tvs.find({ $and: [ { brand: {$in: ["LG", "Samsung"]} },{ size: {$in: ["37"] }}, { price: { $gte: 0 }  }, { price: { $lte: 499 } } ] })
```

Answer (score 0):

You should look into what is happening with you code:

> db.tvs.find( { brand: { $in: ['LG', 'Samsung']} } , { screensize: { $in: ['37', '42']}} )

The query you put is some thing like
`db.collectionName.find({},{});` 
Check this [docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/), It clearly says `db.collection.find({<criteria>}, {<projection>})`. So your query should be constructed such that it should belong to the first parameter not the `<projection>`.

In your case as mentioned above, the second query you wanted to make is going as second parameter which is intrepreted as for *projection*.
 The [projection](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/#projections) parameter specifies which fields to return. 
Projection parameter should be constructed as follows:
`{'FieldName':1}` 
Where, `1` for the field to be returned in result otherwise `0` to explicitly excluded.

So coming to the answer you are looking for is as below:
       `db.tvs.find(`**`{`**`brand:{$in: ['LG', 'Samsung']}, screensize: {$in: ['37', '42']}`**`}`**`)`